# How to populate jquery data accordingly/individually to Cards?

Tags: php, jquery

Im new to Laravel framework and im trying to develop a simple car listing web using Bootstrap Cards. I've successfully implemented AJAX Get including populating data from Controller using Jquery append() method. However it is displaying all cars in one `Card`. How to populate each Cards containing each car?. [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppjWE.png) [console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKk03.png)

```
public function GetCars(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $cars = Car::all();

            return response()->json( $cars );
        }
 }
```

```
   <div class="album py-1">
        <div class="container bg-light">
            <div class="row py-2">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm">
                            <div class="hover-container">
                                        <img src="" class="image img-thumbnail">
                                        <a class="Viewbtn text-decoration-none" href="#" style="font-size: small">View</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body CarDetail">
                                <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Make:<span class="car_Make"></span></p>
                                <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Model:<span class="car_Model"></span></p>
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <p class="font-italic table_data">Price: RM <span class="car_Year"></span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button id="testbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">AJAX</button>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#testbtn').click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: '/ajax/getCar',
                  success : function (data) {
                      $.each(data, function( i, car ) {
                          $('.car_Make').append(car.make);
                          $('.car_Model').append(car.model+'<br>');
                          $('.car_Year').append(car.year+'<br>');
                      });
                  }
              });
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @mgarcia But he uses the `append` function with should append data to the element.

@Marcus Did you try to `console.log` your data and check what is the result?

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu, you are right (I deleted my previous comment to not cause confusion)! Even so, he only has one HTML Element for inserting the cars info. If he wants a card for each car, he will have to recreate the HTML for each card.

Comment: @mgarcia thanks for your reply. Yep the data is a Car object in json format. I want to populate the data fetched from ajax the HTML elements above the <script>

Comment: @yes i've tried `console.log` and `append` and it works fine. Problem is i don't know how to display the data into Cards like the

Comment: Can you add to your question the data you are getting in the ajax success callback? Also, what's the HTML for each car in your code (from which node to which node)? And where should the HTML of the other cars it be appended?

Comment: @mgarcia sorry if my question confuse you. I've attached an image in my question tagged as `current result` which is my current `append`result

Comment: Yes! You are concatenating all the car informations in the only HTML card you have. But I need to know what HTML corresponds to a single card. Can you elaborate a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) in order to see your relevant HTML and CSS? There is no need to incorporate the ajax call, you can directly use the data you are receiving from server.

Comment: @mgarcia the AJAX callback is successful. For now, i'll like to display the data within the CarDetail(card) `div`. But it is displaying all cars in one card. How to contain each car in a Card?

Comment: its not corresponding to any other HTML as im trying to do it within one HTML. Is it possible?

Comment: @MarcusChan When you use the code. Does it print all the cars? What is the output after ajax.success?

Comment: Yep its printing all the cars in one card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what are you meaning?

I created an example, where I'm using some rows from your console.log data.

**Explanation:**
I am iterating throught the data array. If it is first iteration I'm adding data (one `CarDetail` div exists in your code.

For the next iterations I am cloning the `CarDetail` div and fill with next data.

Of course,there are more posibilities how to add your data to page. For example, you can fill the first item in page and then iterate from the second to the last (in that case you won't need the if/else condition) or you can add the HTML code in a JS variable. Personally, I wouldn't do that because it looks very ugly and the readability of the code could get worse.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
   {id:31,make:"Audi",model:"R8",year:2000},
   {id:32,make:"Ferrari",model:"FF",year:2000},
   {id:33,make:"Mazda",model:"Rx-7",year:2000},
   {id:34,make:"Ferrari",model:"F12",year:2012},
   {id:35,make:"Porsche",model:"911",year:2015},
   {id:36,make:"Land Rover",model:"Vogue",year:2015},
   {id:37,make:"Mercedes Benz",model:"SL350",year:2013},
   {id:38,make:"Ferrari",model:"F12",year:2013},
   {id:39,make:"Ferrari",model:"458",year:2013},
  ];
  
  $.each(data, function( i, car ) {
    if(i == 0) {
      $('.card').find('.car_Make').text(car.make);
      $('.card').find('.car_Model').text(car.model);
      $('.card').find('.car_Year').text(car.year);
    } else {
      var carDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone();
      carDetailCloned.find('.car_Make').text(car.make);
      carDetailCloned.find('.car_Model').text(car.model);
      carDetailCloned.find('.car_Year').text(car.year);
      
      $('.card-container').append(carDetailCloned); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.CarDetail{background-color:red;margin-bottom:2em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album py-1">
  <div class="container bg-light">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 card-container">
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm">
          <div class="hover-container">
            <img src="" class="image img-thumbnail">
              <a class="Viewbtn text-decoration-none" href="#" style="font-size: small">View
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body CarDetail">
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Make:
              <span class="car_Make"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Model:
              <span class="car_Model"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <p class="font-italic table_data">Price: RM 
                <span class="car_Year"></span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="testbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">AJAX</button>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I edited my code to clone `<div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm"` for every card and add data in there. Moreover, I add a `card-container` class in the parent element to use it when I append a new car. Is that enough?

Comment: Yep this is the result is want ! but it is still displayed in one `Card` as `CarDetail` is the card body. How to populate them into separate cards?

Comment: @MarcusChan So you want every card to be one `<div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm"></div>`. And to have for every car one dive with data. Am I right?

Comment: @MarcusChan If the answer helped you, please tag it as best answer to close the question. Thank you!